# How to get request metrics for search:suggest http query in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

Since we are using rather large db, I'm trying to grab some statistics on suggestion requests. It seems that

```
 "options": {
   ...
   "return-metrics": true
 }
```

is not working for suggest endpoint. Is there any way to get metrics for such requests?